# STL find performs better than hand-crafted loop

Tags: c++, stl, assembly, find, performance

I have some question. Given the following C++ code fragment:

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

struct incrementor
{
  incrementor() : curr_() {}

  unsigned int operator()()
  { return curr_++; }

private:
  unsigned int curr_;
};

template<class Vec>
char const* value_found(Vec const& v, typename Vec::const_iterator i)
{
  return i==v.end() ? "no" : "yes";
}


template<class Vec>
typename Vec::const_iterator find1(Vec const& v, typename Vec::value_type val)
{
  return find(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
}


template<class Vec>
typename Vec::const_iterator find2(Vec const& v, typename Vec::value_type val)
{
  for(typename Vec::const_iterator i=v.begin(), end=v.end(); i<end; ++i)
    if(*i==val) return i;
  return v.end();
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  typedef vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator iter;
  vector<unsigned int> vec;
  vec.reserve(10000000);

  boost::progress_timer pt;

  generate_n(back_inserter(vec), vec.capacity(), incrementor());
  //added this line, to avoid any doubts, that compiler is able to
  // guess the data is sorted
  random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  cout << "value generation required: " << pt.elapsed() << endl;

  double d;
  pt.restart();
  iter found=find1(vec, vec.capacity());
  d=pt.elapsed();
  cout << "first search required: " << d << endl;
  cout << "first search found value: " << value_found(vec, found)<< endl;


  pt.restart();
  found=find2(vec, vec.capacity());
  d=pt.elapsed();
  cout << "second search required: " << d << endl;
  cout << "second search found value: " << value_found(vec, found)<< endl;


  return 0;
}
```

On my machine (Intel i7, Windows Vista) STL find (call via find1) runs about 10 times faster than the hand-crafted loop (call via find2). I first thought that Visual C++ performs some kind of vectorization (may be I am mistaken here), but as far as I can see assembly does not look the way it uses vectorization. Why is STL loop faster? Hand-crafted loop is identical to the loop from the STL-find body.

I was asked to post program's output. Without shuffle:

```
value generation required: 0.078
first search required: 0.008
first search found value: no
second search required: 0.098
second search found value: no
```

With shuffle (caching effects):

```
value generation required: 1.454
first search required: 0.009
first search found value: no
second search required: 0.044
second search found value: no
```

Many thanks,

dusha.

P.S. I return the iterator and write out the result (found or not), because I would like to prevent compiler optimization, that it thinks the loop is not required at all. The searched value is obviously not in the vector.

P.P.S. I was asked to post assembly generated for the find functions. Here it is:

```
found=find1(vec, vec.capacity());
001811D0  lea         eax,[esp+5Ch] 
001811D4  call        std::vector<unsigned int,std::allocator<unsigned int> >::capacity (1814D0h) 
001811D9  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+60h] 
001811DD  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+64h] 
001811E1  cmp         esi,ecx 
001811E3  je          wmain+180h (1811F0h) 
001811E5  cmp         dword ptr [esi],eax 
001811E7  je          wmain+180h (1811F0h) 
001811E9  add         esi,4 
001811EC  cmp         esi,ecx 
001811EE  jne         wmain+175h (1811E5h) 



found=find2(vec, vec.capacity());
001812AE  lea         eax,[esp+5Ch] 
001812B2  call        std::vector<unsigned int,std::allocator<unsigned int> >::capacity (1814D0h) 
001812B7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+60h] 
001812BB  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+64h] 
001812BF  cmp         ecx,edx 
001812C1  je          wmain+262h (1812D2h) 
001812C3  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],eax 
001812C5  je          wmain+34Fh (1813BFh) 
001812CB  add         ecx,4 
001812CE  cmp         ecx,edx 
001812D0  jne         wmain+253h (1812C3h)
```

find2 uses ecx-register instead of esi. What is the difference between these two registers? Can it be that esi assumes the pointer to be properly aligned and therefore brings additional performance?

Read some assembly reference ecx is just a counter, whereas esi is the memory source. So I think STL algorithm knows that Random Access Iterator is properly aligned and therefore uses memory pointers. Where in the non-STL version there is no speculation how the alignment is. Am I right?

Comment: How much faster? Can you post your program output?

Comment: In every kind of experiment a single data point means nothing. I suggest you to repeat in a loop each search, measuring the time at each iteration and in the end getting the mean and the standard deviation of your measured times. The mean should take out the most of the measurement noise (both "warming" the cache and having random fluctuations compensate themselves) and the stddev should give you a measure of how big are such fluctuations, and so how reliable is your result. If, after doing this, the times still differ more than 2σ, you should probably take a closer look with a profiler.

Comment: did it as you suggested... the results are: first search required: 0.01004, second search required: 0.02006. Just ran the loop 100 times and calculated the average.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea: `i<end` Use `i != end`

Comment: find1() assigns to found during construction. find2() assigns to found using copy construction. Its probably not a big deal but when timing you should always do the same thing everywhere (except for the thing you are timming).

Comment: @dusha: well, then we have a situation `:)` What about the stddev?

Comment: I am not that great in assembly... Can someone double-check if loop unrolling is used as kotlinski suggests? I see there that index register is incremnted by 4, but loop seems to be stepping by 1... I am in doubt.

Comment: @dusha: You should post the disassembly.

Comment: You really mean C++ Standard Library, not STL.

Comment: STL is Standard Template Library... Wich is referenced so in the literature.

Comment: @dusha: All registers are the same. Some registers have special meanings when it comes to maintaining data between function calls (like return addresses), but there's a reason it's called general-purpose, and that's because they are all the same.

Answer (score 6):

Visual C++'s `find` algorithm uses unchecked iterators, whereas your hand written loop is using checked iterators.

<s>My other guess is that you're calling `std::vector<t>::end()` on every iteration of your loop in `find2`, while `std::find` results in only one call to the begin and end accessors.</s>

I am an idiot.

Comment: If you look at the code, you see that end() is not called every iteration.

Comment: @dusha: But `find` can amortize the cost of the check by checking only upon entry to the algorithm -- it will use unchecked operations internally even if the algorithm is still checked.

Comment: The checked/unchecked iterators issue is the key.  If you add `#define _SCL_SECURE 0` at the beginning of the program, find2 becomes as fast as find1.

Comment: @Adrian: You might also have to play with `_SCL_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` -- not sure.

Comment: Checked iterators:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Yttrill: this is not the reason. I tested it with #define _SCL_SECURE 0, that does not help. So do not let others mislead others!

Comment: @dusha: Where did you put the #define for _SCL_SECURE 0 ? It must be before **any** standard C++ header in order to work. (Well, technically not before some, but a lot of headers may indirectly include `algorithm`) Also, if your program has multiple translation units, it must be set that way in each unit, otherwise it's an ODR violation.

Comment: @Billy: In  the first test I put as the first statement into the stdafx.h, after it did not help I went to the Project Properties|C/C++/Preprocessor and added the definition: _SCL_SECURE=0. Both did not help. Do you have more suggestions. But anyway, why should release build use checked_iterators? And moreover, why is different assembly generated, which only differs with two registers. I think the question is: Why is esi register faster than ecx?

Comment: @dusha: Well, my suggestion is simply to use `std::find` :P

Comment: @dusha: Also check the _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING setting. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: @Billy: I use STL algos all the time... IMO they are more expressive. But I would like to understand, why compiler optimizes the find algorithm different as identical body of find.

Comment: @Billy: Just checked _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING setting, which is turned off => no difference. But I don't think that exchanged register (as assembly shows) would do iterator checks.

Comment: No idea then. Better to use `std::find` anyway.

Comment: @Billy: You should strike through the hole text in your post. I think it is not correct, to mislead users and let them vote for it, since we clarified, that your approach does not solve the problem.

Comment: @dusha: In the general case though, this would be a good answer. And I've not done benchmarking confirming this answer wrong. I happen to agree with @DeadMG's answer in that I think your timer is broken. I'm leaving this here for future cases if anyone is debugging a similar issue, because the checked behavior is a 50+% overhead in some cases.

Comment: @Billy: My timer is not broken, since I implemented the timer proposed by DeadMG and did further tests with it. Than I would be polite enough to state in the answer, that tests have shown that this proposal does not solve the issue or either explains it, but: .... On the other hand: Not doing benchmarking to not confirm the answer is wrong is a very opportunistic way of handling the issue. If you leave the answer as is, I will ask other admins for solution, since the answer is really misleading and furthermore, as assembly shows has nothing to do with iterators!!!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you compile your code in release mode with [checked iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) turned off

Set _SECURE_SCL=0 in your preprocessor definitions.

Also, boost::progress_timer has a resolution of milliseconds I believe (it is based on std::clock), this makes it very unreliable for accurate measurements of short durations. You need to make the code that you measure significantly slower so that you get rid of other factors (such as your process being on hold and so on). You should measure using the high performance counters as suggested by DeadMG.

Comment: I compile it in release mode. Did it, no difference. checked iterators are used in STL and in my loop, because it is an iterator property...

Comment: @dusha: Where did you put the `#define`? It must occur before the actual inclusion of `find`.

Comment: @dusha:  Release mode is not enough.  You need to explicitly disable checked iterators.  Defining `_SECURE_SCL` to 0 at the top of the program makes the hand-written loop as fast as `stl::find`.

Answer (score 1):

Your measurement methodology is broken. Measuring the execution speed of code is very difficult to do correctly, because the total elapsed time depends on factors which may not be explicitly controlled by the code you've written.

Some things to check (you may consider some of these obvious):

- What optimisation settings are you using? You are testing a release build, right?
- You said you've checked the assembly code generated by the STL version and it isn't using vectorisation. But maybe it's using some other common optimisation method such as loop unrolling?
- Why are you using `i < end` rather than `i != end` in your loop? (I actually doubt this makes any difference, but who knows?)

---

(My original answer was completely stupid -- not sure why it got a vote -- I'm leaving it here since some of the comments relate to it)

In this case, I suspect you're just seeing the effects of the memory hierarchy. When you call find1(), the CPU has to read all the data from RAM. That data will then be stored in the CPU's cache, which is much (easily 10 to 100 times) faster than accessing RAM. When you call find2(), the CPU can read the whole array from cache memory, and so find2() takes less time to execute.

To get some more evidence, try swapping the code so that you measure find2() first and then find1(). If your results get reversed, it's likely that you're seeing the effect of the cache. If they don't, then it's something else.

**Edit**
After some further thought (actually, just after *some* thought), I think my original suspicion must be incorrect (the size of the array you're searching through makes it unlikely that the entire array has been put into the cache). There may still be cache effects, but they are probably somewhat more subtle. Still, try reversing the measurements anyway, it'd be interesting to see what effect it has.

Comment: The vector is sizeof(unsigned int)*10 000 000 bytes. Isn't that too big to fit in the cpu cache? Also the OP says that find1 (the first call) is faster. So your explanation seems a bit off.

Comment: Yes. My suggestion is bogus for a couple of reasons (the data is too large, and of course it would be in the cache immediately after it's been generated, too). The cache may still be playing a part in the speed difference, but not a totally simple part.

Comment: find2 takes more time to execute! And even if I swap the execution the result is the same.

Comment: Checked your points... The only thing: I changed '<' to '!=' with no difference. What prevents the compiler to unroll my hand-crafted loop? It still knows that I use random access iterator...

Comment: The compiler probably isn't unrolling your loop because modern compilers do not unroll anything, because unrolling usually slows modern processors down. Ultra-tight loops are usually faster than unrolled ones because of reduced cache access, easier branch prediction, and easier instruction pipeline fill etc etc etc. The smaller it is, the better the caching at all levels, and thus faster. This isn't universally true but the best heuristic for a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

find doesn't take a value_type, it takes a const value_type&. Now, I would say that for unsigned int, this should make no difference. However, it's perfectly possible that your optimizer just didn't notice this, and failed to correctly optimize your loop body.

Edit: What I would suggest is that you're kind of lying to the compiler with your use of the for loop. You could rewrite it as

```
typename Vec::iterator i, end;
i = vec.begin();
end = vec.end();
while(i != end && *i != val)
    i++;
return i;
```

Of course, the guy who wrote std::find knows exactly how smart the optimizer is, and what exactly it can and can't cope with.

Edit: I ran your test on my machine. It's an i7 930, no overclock, on Visual Studio 2010. I replaced the boost::progress_timer with the High Performance Counter.

```
__int64 frequency, begin, end;
QueryPerformanceCounter(frequency);
double d;
QueryPerformanceCounter(begin);
iter found=find1(vec, vec.capacity());
QueryPerformanceCounter(end);
d = ((end - begin) / (double)frequency) * 1000000;
cout << "first search required: " << d << endl;
cout << "first search found value: " << value_found(vec, found)<< endl;


QueryPerformanceCounter(begin);
found=find2(vec, vec.capacity());
QueryPerformanceCounter(end);
d = ((end - begin) / (double)frequency) * 1000000;
cout << "second search required: " << d << endl;
cout << "second search found value: " << value_found(vec, found)<< endl;
```

Says that both of them took 0.24 (roughly) nanoseconds to operate- that is, there is no difference. My suggestion is that your optimizer is just immature and that your version of std::find is written exactly to present the correct optimizations, whereas your find just doesn't tick the correct optimization boxes.

Edit: Your timing data is clearly busted. My i7 is running in 0.23 nanoseconds- that is, 0.00000023 seconds, whereas yours wants 0.008 seconds. Unless my i7 is about 40,000 times faster than yours, there's no way. There is no way that an i7 will take so long to traverse only ten million items. Of course, I'm actually running 64bit Windows 7, although didn't compile in 64bit mode.

Going to post the disassembler now.

find1:

```
00F810D3  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+34h]  
00F810D7  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+3Ch]  
00F810DB  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+38h]  
00F810DF  sub         eax,esi  
00F810E1  sar         eax,2  
00F810E4  cmp         esi,ecx  
00F810E6  je          main+0B3h (0F810F3h)  
00F810E8  cmp         dword ptr [esi],eax  
00F810EA  je          main+0B3h (0F810F3h)  
00F810EC  add         esi,4  
00F810EF  cmp         esi,ecx  
00F810F1  jne         main+0A8h (0F810E8h)
```

find2:

```
00F8119A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+34h]  
00F8119E  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+3Ch]  
00F811A2  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+38h]  
00F811A6  sub         eax,ecx  
00F811A8  sar         eax,2  
00F811AB  cmp         ecx,edx  
00F811AD  jae         main+17Fh (0F811BFh)  
00F811AF  nop  
00F811B0  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],eax  
00F811B2  je          main+254h (0F81294h)  
00F811B8  add         ecx,4  
00F811BB  cmp         ecx,edx  
00F811BD  jb          main+170h (0F811B0h)  
00F811BF  mov         esi,edx
```

You can see that find2 *is* slightly different to find1. I checked by replacing the call to find2 with another find1 call which *does* produce identical disassembly. Curious that they produce different assembly.

Comment: I do in on a 32bit machine.... sizeof(reference)==sizeof(unsigned int). Why should this matter? And find is called only once, therefore it just does not copy the value one time only and runs the loop with the reference.

Comment: The code you posted is not the implementation of my find... But just tested it. It is slower as find. Actually my hand-crafted loop provides the same performance as your snippet.

Comment: @dusha: It matters, if the optimizer can't spot that they're the same.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the High Performance Counters. boost::progress_timer is not intended for performance benchmarks like this - it is based on std::clock.

Comment: I run my code in VMWare... That can explain the delay. I will test the Perf Counter suggestion. Please double-check that you retrieve the frequency in your test correctly (QueryPerformanceFrequency and not QueryPerformanceCounter).

Comment: @dusha: I write this code all the time and it's definitely correct. I overloaded QPF/QPC to avoid that nasty cast you usually get when calling them, but that's it.

Comment: @dusha: You should never benchmark like this inside of a VM. For the most part VM times will agree with real hardware, but not always (i.e. if one item happens to use an instruction the VM has to emulate rather than hypervise)

Comment: @Billy: If the VM behaves differently with regards to different instructions, then it's possible that the very slightly different disassembly in the second version is just unhappy with the VM.

Comment: "no way that an i7 will take so long" - the bottleneck surely is memory, not the processor!

Comment: Are you on 32 or 64 bit windows? I use 32bit OS... I just replaced the boost::progress_timer with PerfCounters, but they still differ by a factor of 2. I run it in VS 2008.

Comment: @kotlinski: i7s share the same, for example, cache timings, and while he COULD be having memory bottleneck issues, his memory is not going to be 40,000 times slower than mine, as we share the same cache size and therefore the same memory swap to RAM requirements.

Comment: @dusha: VS2010, and I'm on 64bit Windows 7. I still suspect that the VM is making the most difference here.

Comment: But I don't think so... I remember to test this issue before on a non-VM Windows and it still persist. Your statement is: VM runs some assembly statements better than others and I was able found out which ones ;) I don't think so. I think MS tuned VS2010 somewhere. Try to compile you code as 32bit executable...

Comment: @dusha: I did. I'm running on 64bit but compiling as 32bit. I also compiled as 64bit- the disassembly was identical. You need to post the disassembly.

Comment: Just ran my 32bit exe on Windows 2008 server host OS (where all VMs run) with the same performance drawbacks for find2. OK, 64bit OSs execute 32bit executable in some kind of VMs. But I virtualize using VMware and Windows uses own virtualization and both fail with assembly statements from find2. Not really plausible.

Comment: Ok, posted the assembly in my original message.

Comment: @dusha: 64bit OS doesn't execute 32bit in a VM- it's a processor feature, not an OS feature. However, I'm also not seeing the plausibility of it treating very similar instructions so differently.

Comment: I mean WOW64: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64, 32bit code runs through this layer. This is in my opinion some sort of virtualization. It is not just a processor feature.

Comment: @dusha: That layer handles code interoperation between Windows and 32bit code, not between 32bit code and the CPU. "Wow64cpu.dll, which takes care of switching the processor from 32-bit to 64-bit mode.". Ergo, the CPU has a 32bit-mode.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it also ensures compatiblity between 32bit and 64bit libs. Not all executables are self containing. They might link to other 32bit api system calls etc.

Comment: @dusha: It's not any form of virtualization -- 32 bit code runs completely natively. The WOW64 bits are needed only for 32 bit code calls into the 64 bit Kernel. Your code uses no such syscalls, therefore WOW64 isn't going to be a factor here.

Comment: You didn't post a disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Visual C++ myself, but with GCC I also got the result that `find2` is a little slower. However, I was able to make `find2` just slightly faster than `find1` by manually unrolling the loop:

```
template<class Vec>
typename Vec::const_iterator find2(Vec const& v, typename Vec::value_type val)
{
  for(typename Vec::const_iterator i=v.begin(), end=v.end(); i != end; ) {
    if (i[0]==val) return i;
    if (i[1]==val) return i + 1;
    i += 2;
  }
  return v.end();
}
```

My guess to why `std::find` is faster is that the compiler has all the information to figure out that the vector size is a multiple of 2, and that it is possible to do this unrolling.

Another guess is that it is just a tradeoff between space/size - that the compiler skips this optimization in the general case.

Comment: Very interesting. Just for reference, could you post processor, g++ version and compile flags?

Comment: I really wonder why is VC or G++ do not unroll hand-crafted loops? This is a part of their optimization... Tested it... My loop with hand-crafted unrolling is still slower... Your code has a minor bug... return must return i+OffsetValue and not just i.

Comment: @dusha: noticed and fixed that.

Comment: @dusha: I checked again - my timing differences are much smaller than yours - so this is probably not the explanation for your problem.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of C/C++ users complain that once they write an specialisation of a function, the non specialised version out performs it!

The reason is simply once you are writing optimisation passes on your compiler back end, you will think of ways to improve the `std::find` code generation and hence it out performs your implementation.

Also node that `std::find` for VC++ at least, has different versions, which will invoke different function and search algorithms for different kinds of iterators.

So all an all I think the compiler seems to understand your data is sorted and hence perform better search.

Comment: "So all an all I think the compiler seems to understand your data is sorted..." <- this is impossible.

Comment: I hardly doubt it, but just put random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end()); after the generate call. Now the difference is the same (times 10), but the overall time shorter. I can only exlain, that part of the data is still in the cache.

Comment: Actually the first 2 lines are probably true: I certainly use exactly this technique to improve my optimiser.

Comment: It is possible. Even if the compiler couldn't guess the data, its apparent from the assembly that it could guess the data structure better and hence generates better code.